# Does retrying to process a kafka message forever cause a consumer rebalance

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-retry

I have a kafka consumer method annotated @kafkalistener. I have set the retry template on the container and the retry config is such that it would always retry for a couple of exceptions, if occurred while processing the msg. I have set max-poll-records to 1. If this situation occurs in real time and the consumer keeps retrying the msg forever, will the broker think that this consumer is dead and trigger a rebalance? Or, while retrying does the consumer poll for the same msg that was failed to process? If this is true, since poll is happening, there wouldn't be any rebalancing is my assumption. Also I am manually committing offsets, so my enable.auto.commit property is set to false and ack-mode is manual. Can anyone please clarify? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when using none-stateful retry (the default) at the listener adapter level, it will cause a rebalance when `max.poll.interval.ms` is exceeded.

You should use [Stateful Retry](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#stateful-retry) instead.

In that case, the exception is thrown to the container and a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` re-seeks the unprocessed partitions (including the failed record). You still need to ensure the largest backoff time is less than the poll interval. There is no need to set `max.poll.records` to 1 because seeks are done on all unprocessed partitions.

Starting with version 2.3, you can eliminate retry at the listener level and just use a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. After reading this, I have a few more questions, which I will ask as another question. But yeah, this is the accepted answer for my question. Thanks again. @Gary Russell